# Minimum residential requirements For PhD

Tags: part-time

I have a permanent Job that I don't intend to give up. I wish to pursue PhD. All I can manage to get is 2 years of leave. Beyond that I will have to resume my job and I can continue research work along with that. What are the typical requirements?

I am aiming to get a PhD position in CS/EE department. Are there some departments which would accommodate such cases. Please share your insights/suggestions.

Comment: Just go part time after two years. What country are you in? PhD course requirements (and therefore attendance) vary considerably.

Comment: Why not do a PhD part-time and just do some short residentials? Some countries do not need coursework, so working on your research during your own time is easier rather than having to attend mandatory coursework.

Comment: I can (sort of) answer this for the UK but not anywhere else. You need to specify a country.

Comment: this is superficially contradictory.  You have a permanent job and don’t want to give it up, but you are also aiming to get a position in CS/EE?

Comment: Possibly related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/132960/93566